# How to proper classify vue's method?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to write a method on vue, the original code is here, it workable.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
         buttonText : 'A'
  },
  methods: {
    clickA: _.throttle(function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('A clicked', time)
      this.buttonText = 'my button' + time; 
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button type="button" @click="clickA">{{buttonText}}</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) and classify it as following, it compiled but the click can not work.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  clickA () {
    throttle(function () {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('A clicked', time)
      this.buttonText = 'my button' + time;
    }, 1000) // max one submit per second
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`throttle` returns a function  . so invoke the `throttle()` and  assign it to `clickA` like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  clickA = throttle(function () {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('A clicked', time)
    }, 1000) // max one submit per second
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<button type="button" @click="clickA">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

**script**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
    buttonText = 'my button';

  clickA = throttle( () => {
      var date = new Date();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('A clicked', time)
       /// change button text

        this.buttonText = 'my button' + time;


    }, 1000) // max one submit per second
}
</script>
```

Comment: In vue-class-component's document, methods can be written as methods directly.  Why it should be written as property here?

Comment: @DanielYCLin because loodash's `throttle` return a new function which we are assigning to a properrty

Comment: Could you modify the question and your answer to show the 'this' usage too? For example, when click, change the button's text